# How to visualize a multi-level graph with both undirected edges and directed edges?

Tags: graph, mermaid

How to visualize a multi-level graph with both undirected edges and directed edges? I need to draw a graph consists of a minimum spanning tree with undirected edges at each level, and directed edges between levels. Need to add text annotations for vertices and edges. Any tools built for this?

I tried mermaid inside markdown software including Notion/Typora, but can't fulfill this task.